# How to construct a sentence like "I enjoyed seeing you"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, contemporary-latin, english

please could I have a little guidance on how to say "I enjoyed seeing you". Is there a more idiomatic way of phrasing in latin (e.g. it was a please to see you)?
If not, would 'seeing' be a gerundive (presumably in the ablative) i.e. frui te vivendo, or is it simply an indirect statement, in which case it would take acc + inf. i.e. frui te videre.
Final question - is there a resource where I can find constructions like this in the future... I have looked at L&S but I couldn't find any reference to this sort of construction...
Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Hey Paul, the linked question should also provide an answer to this one. Also, read the comments too for the fuller discussion. If you still feel you have lingering questions, feel free to edit your question and mention what still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Shorter cmw: Subordinate clauses in Latin generally prefer to use the infinitive (_to see_) rather than the active participle / gerund (_seeing_). You could do it several ways but the most idiomatic would be "to see you once more was such a pleasure" if you truly mean taking the person in by the eyes was what you most enjoyed. If you're actually talking about the conversation, the meeting, or the time spent with the person, _you'd actually say that_: "time spent with you is always a pleasure" &c.

Comment: Note that (a) "I enjoyed" would be *fructus sum*, and (b) *frui* does not take either an AcI or a *quod* clause, and generally asthma seems unsuited for your purpose.